# filebeat-kafka:WARN producer/broker/0 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

when filebeat output data to kafka , there are many warning message in filebeat log.

..

```
*WARN producer/broker/0 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space

*WARN producer/broker/0 maximum request accumulated, waiting for space
```

..

nothing special in my filebeat config:

..

```
output.kafka:

  hosts: ["localhost:9092"]

  topic: "log-oneday"
```

..

i have also updated these socket setting in kafka:

...

```
socket.send.buffer.bytes=10240000

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=10240000

socket.request.max.bytes=1048576000

queued.max.requests=1000
```

...

but it did not work.

is there something i missing? or i have to increase those number bigger?

besides , no error or exception found in kafka server log

is there any expert have any idea about this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have only one partition in your topic. Try to increase partitions for the topic. See the links below for more information.

## More Partitions Lead to Higher Throughput

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic

Try the following command (replacing info with your particular use case):

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --alter --topic my_topic_name  --partitions 40
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure 3 things:

- Brokers
- Filebeat kafka output
- Consumer

Here a example (change paths according your environment).

Broker configuration:

```
# open kafka server configuration file
vim /opt/kafka/config/server.properties

# add this line
# The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka.
message.max.bytes=100000000

# restart kafka service
systemctl restart kafka.service
```

Filebeat kafka output:

```
output.kafka:
  ...
  max_message_bytes: 100000000
```

Consumer configuration:

```
# larger than the max.message.size
max.partition.fetch.bytes=200000000
```